# Encoding errors with StringIO and read_csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

I am using an API to get some data. The data returned is in Unicode (not a dictionary / json object).

## get data

```
data = []
for urls in api_call_list:
    data.append(requests.get(urls))
the data looks like this:

>>> data[0].text
u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Taylor Swift;33100;0.83;0.20\r\n'

>>> data[1].text
u'Country;Celebrity;Song Volume;CPP;Index\r\nus;Rihanna;28100;0.76;0.33\r\n'
```

I use this code to convert this to a dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO     
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(d.text), sep = ";") for d in data])
```

Works just fine except when there are non-english characters involved in the results, specially, Korean, Chinese or Japanese. It completely garbles them. I tried adding the encoding argument to read_csv with utf_8, cp1252 and iso-8859-1 as values. None of these worked.

How should i read this data correctly?

Comment: did you try `[pd.read_csv(StringIO(d.text) for d in data]`?

Comment: just did, it doesn't work. Though there is clearly a semi-colon separator . . without it, i got just a single column!

Comment: No, I accidentally dropped the semi-colon, what I meant was access the `.text` attribute of each element in `data`, so `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(d.text, sep=";") for d in data])`

Comment: oh my bad, it is d.text in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis and research , I was able to identify the problem. The unicode returned by the API was decoded or did not have the correct encoding but it can be set. So what i did is added a line to set the encoding for the payload from requests.

```
data = []
for urls in api_call_list:
    r = requests.get(urls)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data.append(r)
```

and then added encoding argument to read_csv :

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(d.text), sep = ";", encoding='utf-8') for d in data])
```

that set it right. the documentation is here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/